# Incorrect sorting using shortauthor in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber, sorting

I use biblatex with biber backend and alphabetic style. If I declare a shortauthor as described in the manual [2.3.3 Corporate Authors and Editors](http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) my bibliography sorting is incorrect. REA17 should be before Tec12... any Ideas? Thank You!

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[
    backend     = biber,
    style       = alphabetic,
    sorting     = nyt,          %Sort by name, year, title.
    sortlocale  = auto,         %If german with babel use auto
    sortcites   = true,         %sort in \cite{}
    natbib      = false,        %loads \citet, \citep, \citealt and \citealp
    hyperref    = auto,
    backref     = false,        %List page numbers to references
    isbn        = false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{NASARadEff,LT2012TR}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

And the external bibfile:

```
@techreport{LT2012TR,
  title = {ELDRS Radiation Testing of the RH118W Op-Amp for Linear Technology},
  author = {Linear Technology},
  institution = {Radiation Assured Devices},
  year = {2012}
}
@online{NASARadEff,
  title={Radiation Effects and Analysis Home Page},
  author={{The Radiation Effects and Analysis Group (REAG)}},
  shortauthor={REAG},
  organization={{National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA)}},
  year={2017},
  url = "https://radhome.gsfc.nasa.gov/"
}
```

Comment: Well, you use `sorting=nyt` so the first sort criterion is "name", and "Linear..." comes before "The Radiation...". By your bibliography sorting being "incorrect" you mean that you expect it to be sorted by the entry's label? If so, you should use `sorting = anyt`.

Comment: gusbrs is absolutely right. With `sorting=nyt` the name part of sorting is by `author` and not `shorthauthor`. The suggested `sorting = anyt` is the default if you load `style=alphabetic` (but you overwrite the default with the explicit `sorting=nyt`). `natbib = false, hyperref = auto, backref = false` are all the default settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `sorting=nyt` so the first sort criterion is "name", and "Linear..." comes before "The Radiation...". Biblatex is only sorting according to the criteria you specified.

If you want your bibliography to be sorted by the entry's label, you should specify a sorting which takes that into account. E.g. `sorting = anyt`, which (as well remembered by moewe) is the alphabetic style's default, so you only need to remove `sorting=nyt` to achieve the desired results.

[image]

In full:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{LT2012TR,
    title = {ELDRS Radiation Testing of the RH118W Op-Amp for Linear Technology},
    author = {Linear Technology},
    institution = {Radiation Assured Devices},
    year = {2012}
}
@online{NASARadEff,
    title={Radiation Effects and Analysis Home Page},
    author={{The Radiation Effects and Analysis Group (REAG)}},
    shortauthor={REAG},
    organization={{National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA)}},
    year={2017},
    url = "https://radhome.gsfc.nasa.gov/"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    backend     = biber,
    style       = alphabetic,
    sortlocale  = auto,         %If german with babel use auto
    sortcites   = true,         %sort in \cite{}
    natbib      = false,        %loads \citet, \citep, \citealt and \citealp
    hyperref    = auto,
    backref     = false,        %List page numbers to references
    isbn        = false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{NASARadEff,LT2012TR}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course with `style=alphabetic` `sorting = anyt,` is already the default.

Comment: @moewe, thanks for pointing that out. Answer updated accordingly.